# Unexpected too big length: 186 - weblogic 12

Tags: java, openssl, weblogic, weblogic12c

When I am trying to get private key from .pem file, I am getting

`java.security.KeyManagementException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected too big length: 186`

Code snippet is :

```
  FileInputStream keyfin = new FileInputStream(keyFileName);
  SSLContextWrapper wrapper = SSLContextWrapper.getInstance();
  PrivateKey key = wrapper.inputPrivateKey(keyfin, keyPass.toCharArray());
```

And I am using `weblogic.security.utils.SSLContextWrapper;` weblogic utility.

*NOTE:* When trying with weblogic 10.3, this seems to work, but with weblogic 12.1.1, exception is thrown.

I am generating key using OpenSSL.

How to solve this issue, if anybody else has faced it.

Comment: Is this the same version of java and same key file? Weblogic changed crypto jars (or at least support) between 10 and 12.

Comment: yes, this is same java version and key file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this command on OpenSSL, passed same file as input and output, Weblogic 12c seems to work with this now.

```
rsa -in ${server_key_name}.pem -passin pass:${server_pass} -out {server_key_name}.pem
```